# React DnD - nested component can set props but not parent on drop event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two DropTargets, ComponentA and ComponentB arranged in this structure:

```
<ComponentA
    dropEvent={this.handleRootDropEvent}
>
    <p>Displayed Categories </p>
    {   
        this.state.categories.map((c, idx) =>  
            <ComponentB 
                key={idx}
                parentCat={null}
                thisCat={c}
                level={c.level}
                dropEvent={this.handleDropEvent}
            />
        )   
    }   
</ComponentA>
```

And the problem I'm having in particular is with the drop target spec `drop` function. Both of the DropTargets (for ComponentA and B) have the same drop function defined at the moment:

```
//ComponentB
const targetSpec  = { 
    drop(props, monitor, component) {
        const item = monitor.getItem()
        if (props.thisCat.category_id == item.category_id) return
        component.setState({ droppedItem: item })
        component.setState({ droppedItem: null })
    },  
    canDrop(props, monitor) {
        const item = monitor.getItem() 
        if (props.thisCat.category_id == item.category_id) return false
        return true
    },  
    hover(props, monitor, component){
    }   
}

// Component A
const source = { 
    drop(props, monitor, component) {
        const item = monitor.getItem()
        component.setState({ droppedItem: item })
        component.setState({ droppedItem: null })
    }   
}
```

(I can confirm that both are getting called on drop events, and that item is not null in ComponentA's drop function)

It seems that `component.setState({})` actually changes the props of the component it's called on, or at least that's how I'm able to use it in the case of ComponentB:

```
componentWillReceiveProps = () => {
    if (this.props.droppedItem) {
        this.props.dropEvent(this.props.droppedItem, this.props.thisCat)
    }
}
```

And that code works, I'm able to trigger a function in the parent component (or this case grandparent) of ComponentB by checking for the presence of those props that are set in the drop function.

However, in the same exact `componentWillReceiveProps` function definition in ComponentA, this.props.droppedItem is always undefined.

Any idea what I could try to get the props passed successfully? Am I misunderstanding React DnD's `component.setState({})` API?

Comment: sorry to write here, but the last question with this and `forEach`, you could use the second parameter `thisArg` of `forEach` to handover `this` and take `this` inside of the callback, no need to bind outside, which might not work.

Comment: @NinaScholz thank you, you're very kind! That did indeed fix the problem I had over there.